# ms access autofill date field based on date of previous record

Tags: date, ms-access, default-value, autofill

I have a table that has estimate numbers for each department on a given date (each date is a record with fields EST_DATE, DEPT1, DEPT2, DEPT3, etc.). The date is the indexed primary key (no duplicates).

**When a user creates a new record I would like the date to autofill based on the last record.**

So if the last estimate was for 07/02/2015, the date for the new record should autofill as 07/03/2015. Using a default value based on the current date won't work because these estimates are generated days or weeks in advance. If it matters, the format for field `EST_DATE` is set to `"mm/dd/yyyy"`.

I would prefer to use the default value of the `EST_DATE` field itself, but I can also use event-based VBA since users will normally be entering this estimate data via a bound form.

Comment: the data type is date/time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden textbox named, say, `MaxEstDate`.

Set it's ControlSource to: `=Max([EST_DATE])`.

Set the DefaultValue of the textbox with EST_DATE to: `=[MaxEstDate]`.

Comment: i created a text box called `MaxEstDate`. i set the control source to `=Max([EST_DATE])+1`. it correctly displays the date after that of the last record. when i set the default value of the `EST_DATE` textbox to `=[MaxEstDate]`, it displays the date 12/31/1899. if i set the control source of `MaxEstDate` to `=Max([EST_DATE])`, the date _of_ the last record is displayed and the default value displays as 12/30/1899.

Comment: it works! when i load the form from design view, the default value doesn't load properly. but when i open the form from scratch the text box method works perfectly. thanks @Gustav!